# Is there a way to get the commit message of the source branch in Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Gitlab provides the predefined variable `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME`, is there a way to get the commit message associated with it?

Please note that I want the commit message of the branch that is merging into another branch. I do not want `CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE`, that is the commit message for `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME`

Answer (score 0):

The `CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE` variable will provide the commit message for the commit that triggered the pipeline.

So if you create an MR to merge branch `feature/123` into `main` the `CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE` var will provide the commit message for the source branch(feature/123)

[Gitlab Pre-defined Variables Doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html)

Comment: `CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE` is the commit message for the target branch `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME`

Comment: No, CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE is the commit message of the commit which triggered the pipeline

Comment: From what I see, Gitlab is providing a different commit message from the source branch commit message when merged. The commit message is a combination of the branch name with some other things.

Comment: Thanks, I will check again to make sure.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. That's because the merge request is creating a merge commit. This adds an extra commit to the process which is why you are seeing the branch name. One option would be to change the repository settings to allow fast-forward commits only.